# Using routerLink in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In my angular 2 SPA application , I have defined one of my routes as mentioned below

```
 {path:'acategories/:id/products/:pid' , component:ProductComponent}
```

To use the above route I have defined a routerLink in my template as below

```
<a [routerLink]="['acategories' , product.category , 'products' , product._id ]"> Product </a>
```

But the above routerLink does not generate the link as expected?

I was expecting http://localhost:3000/acategories/books/products/1 but instead it was http://localhost:3000/acategories/books/products/acategories/books/products/1

What needs to be modified in the routerLink ?

Comment: What did you expect? What did you get?

Comment: I think it needs to be `[routerLink]="['/acategories'..` but can you add your related routing modules?

Comment: @echonax , yes indeed , thanks..

Comment: @CleanCrispCode is the issue solved? :O

Comment: Yes solved ! :)

Comment: @CleanCrispCode I'll provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link needs to be:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/acategories' , product.category , 'products' , product._id ]"> Product </a>
```

"/" indicates that this is a full(absolute) path, if you don't include it, it will be relative like the one you are getting.